# Time field doesn't show time with AM/PM properly when use default value

Tags: default-value

I am trying auto fill time field while creating new record.

my field as here what i want to show

[image: What i want to show]

but i am getting like this

my field data type is time

[image: i am getting like this]

i am using default value

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Salesforce Classic, there is no way you can change the display format of time field to AM/PM at the time of editing. However, when you save your record it will show the time in AM/PM format.

In lightning, you can see AM/PM format while editing records.

When using Apex, You can change formats of time field while editing.

Moreover, In formula field you have used:

> TIMEVALUE( TIMENOW() )

and this is wrong. You cannot use TIMEVALUE() on a TIME field because TIME field's value is already in TIME format.

So you only need to write this:

> TIMENOW()

Reference: [Refer to Time TIMEVALUE() function here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed Salesforce lighting supporting this feature with AM and PM via picklist but in classic you have to enter value manually.

Just see the same field in lighting and classic you will come to know the difference.

Comment: This does not answer the original question. The problem is that time doesn't show correctly when the Time fields has the default value.

Comment: Yes it's not showing correct value.. it's a classic feature, the same will work on lighting, that's what I mentioned